# FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix'

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I am running a bigquery command from composer using bash operator to load data from hive to bigquery as below.

```
bq --location=US load --replace --source_format=PARQUET --autodetect --hive_partitioning_mode=CUSTOM --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix=gs://XXX xxx gs://xxx*
```

But its erroring saying `FATAL Flags parsing error: Unknown command line flag 'hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix'`

If i add google-cloud-sdk install command  to the above bash command its working.

I think Google Cloud SDK comes preinstalled in Cloud Composer.I am using composer-1.7.2-airflow-1.10.2

Wondering why its not working if i dont add google sdk install to the above bash command

Answer (score 0):

According to the GCP Composer release notes [document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes), Google [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) tools are continuously updating and flavored with some new features within `Composer-Airflow` growing path.

Therefore, you may facing this issue due to the old SDK components shipped in `composer-1.7.2-airflow-1.10.2`, especially `bq` util that  comes in this environment with no support for [HivePartitioningOptions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/hive-partitioned-loads-gcs#setting_hivepartitioningoptions_using_the_cli) impacting Airflow [*BashOperator*](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/bash_operator/index.html#module-airflow.operators.bash_operator).